# Somar valor total de um resultado com PHP

Tags: php

COlegas.

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
$c = 1;
foreach($xml->resultado as $listar => $valor) {
     if($_POST["respostas"][$c] == $respostas){
            $valor = "1";
            $somar = $c;
        }else{
            $valor = "0";
        }
$c++;
}
echo "Valor Total: " .count($c);
```

A $valor retorna 1 para cada questão acertada, então aparece dessa forma:

```
Resposta A -> 1
Resposta B -> 1
Resposta C -> 1
```

GOstaria de somar do qual desse no total 3, mas está retornando sempre 1.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consegui. Para isso usei:

```
$c = 1;
foreach($xml->resultado as $listar => $valor) {
     if($_POST["respostas"][$c] == $respostas){
            $valor = "1";
            $somar[0] = $c++;
        }else{
            $valor = "0";
        }
}
echo "Valor Total: " .array_sum($somar);
```

Comment: Marque como resposta. São bem vindas na comunidade as perguntas com resposta do próprio autor, desde que não tenham precedentes na documentação de outras perguntas.

Comment: Olá Eduardo. Tentei fazer isso, mas o sistema só permite depois de 2 dias ;)